# building laravel-ready ORM models in sub-package? (what dependencies?)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I've worked with laravel a little in the past, but I'm trying to learn to use the Eloquent ORM. I'm migrating an old project and the original coder used crude data-container classes for the various SQL tables. (this is old code, likely written before many ORMs existed)

I want to refactor this bundle of code to load as a composer package into a new laravel web project (to replace the old site code), but I don't seem to see a stand-alone packagist package for just the Eloquent ORM. (I've worked with Doctrine in the days of Zend2, and Doctrine could be used independently)

How can you create ORM models to be laravel-ready in a sub-package loaded into a laravel website project?  Or is there some other recommended way to handle the data for a sub-package specific to business logic?

SW